# iDRAC7 "Connection failed" when launching virtual console

Tags: remote-access

The web interface for my DRAC 7 interface loads and is responsive (showing correct info), but when I attempt to launch the Virtual Console, I get the following:

I'm not showing anything in the server error log to show why this is failing.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an older question but I wanted to provide an update.  I fixed this in two steps.

1. Configured [Java Console security settings](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml) to include the DRAC hostname.
2. Updated iDRAC firmware version 1.30.30.00 to 2.31.31.30 (using [Dell System Update](https://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/dsu/) DSU)

After the iDRAC update I was able to get in and launch the Virtual Console successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Commenting out line "jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3" in java.security file as mentioned in 
https://www.dell.com/community/Systems-Management-General/iDRAC6-Virtual-Console-Connection-Failed/m-p/6090919/highlight/true#M26068
worked for me.

I was seeing 404s in IE11. To solve it, I had to add idrac IP under Compatibility View

Under idrac, Console, Plug-in Type, it needs to be set to Native.

And it's working for me on IE11. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

For mac users below is a guide.

Take this path: `Mac HD/Library/Internet Plug-Ins`

Once you arrive: Right click the package called: `JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`

Make sure to select “Show package contents”

Once inside this package here is the path: `Contents/Home/lib/security`

Once you are here: Drag the File named `javascript.security` onto your desktop.

Open with text editor and scroll to the bottom until you find:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
```

Once you find it place a `#` in front of it and click save file.

Example:

```
# jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
```

Once the file is saved drag it back into the security folder once prompted just overwrite the existing locked file.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you fixed it in the meantime, but if not, feel free to try this solution I found. Worked for me on OS X (but this is the link to the Windows solution): http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/b/techcenter/archive/2012/05/24/idrac7-virtual-console-enhanced-security-checks-in-the-integrated-dell-remote-access-controller.

Basically, it might be the case that your Windows user home is non-default. In that case, you have to execute the following command to copy over two cert files:

```
copy %USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\Security\trusted.*  <NON_DEFAULT_HOME>\ AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\Security\*
```

Credits (and solution for Linux and OS X) to http://thornelabs.net/2013/10/01/dell-idrac-7-partially-working-in-os-x-mountain-lion-with-java-7.html

Comment: Tried the dell link above.  I'm seeing the same home folder with both commands.   Tried the copy command - says file not found.   Wish I had a workaround as I'd like to avoid the hour drive back to the DC.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and it was because NPAPI plugins are disabled on Chrome. Running in IE resolved it.

Comment: I was using Internet Explorer.

Comment: We had to update iDRAC. Native connections worked best for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost every single java configuration and nothing worked. Newer versions with HTML5 are working perfectly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I used generation 13 server with newest IDRAC and it worked smoothly.